# Horizontal Bar Chart Exactly Like as Following?

Tags: android, android-layout, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am facing some issues in Horizontal Bar Chart. I want to set exactly like as screenshot. I tried some examples but mostly examples of  barchart y values are on right side

XML Code

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
        android:id="@+id/barchart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp" />
```

Java Code

```
 HorizontalBarChart barChart = (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.barchart);

        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        labels.add("Free Lancing");

        // create BarEntry for Bar Group 1
        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 0));

        /*BarDataSet bardataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "Cells");

        BarData data = new BarData(bardataset, bardataset);
        barChart.setData(data); // set the data and list of labels into chart*/


        // creating dataset for Bar Group 2
        BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(entries, "Bar Group 2");
        barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);



        List<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();  // combined all dataset into an arraylist

        dataSets.add(barDataSet2);

// initialize the Bardata with argument labels and dataSet
        BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataSets);
         // set custom bar width
        barChart.setData(data);

        barChart.setBorderWidth(50f);
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly do you want? I am not getting your point.

Answer (score 0):

I have a link for your needs. This library should help you:

[AnyChart-Android](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android)

You implement it in this way:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
            ...
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Add the dependency to the project build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.AnyChart:AnyChart-Android:1.1.2'
}
```

You have there a lot of options. Hope it helps you